# Sum up multiple rankings to overall ranking with different weights

Tags: matlab

I have a 160x2 MATLAB double that is structured as follows

```
   | Vocab |  Math
-------------------------
 1 |   1   |   1
 2 |   3   |   4
 3 |   4   |   3
 4 |   2   |   2
```

In the example above I've simplified things so it's only 4x2 instead of 160x2.

Each column represents one of two classes on which students were graded.

On Vocab, Person 1 was top ranked, then Person 3, then Person 4, then Person 2.

On Math, Person 1 was top ranked, then Person 4, then Person 3, then Person 2.

I want to implement an overall ranking system that combines each person's result on the two classes, and make that overall ranking a third column.

I want write code that is flexible so that Math might be weighted as more important than Vocab. Let's say it's worth twice as much as Vocab.

I had an idea that the weightings could be done by a points system in which fewer points means a better result.

Person 1 was best at Vocab and Math, and receives 1 point for the Vocab ranking, and 2 points (because Math is weighted double) for the Math ranking = **3 total**
Person 2 was worst (fourth) at both Vocab and Math, and receives 4 points for the Vocab ranking + 8 points for the Math ranking = **12 total**
Person 3 gets 2 points for Vocab, and 6 points for Math = **8 total**
Person 4 gets 3 points for Vocab, and 4 points for Math = **7 total**

Based on those points scores, the double should be altered to add a column to represent Overall ranking:

```
   | Vocab |  Math |Overall
-------------------------
 1 |   1   |   1   |   1
 2 |   3   |   4   |   4
 3 |   4   |   3   |   3
 4 |   2   |   2   |   2
```

How can this be efficiently achieved in MATLAB?

I'd like to write code that allows future flexibility to change the weightings so that (for instance) Math is worth three times as much as Vocab. However, I'll never need to add more subjects in - it will always be just Vocab and Math.

I'd like ties to be decided in favour of whoever scored better on Math.

Comment: You got the Vocab scores mixed up

Comment: A mix of simple column operations and `sortrows` will work. Have you tried writing some code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a classic task for [**`accumarray`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
%// persons
p = [1 2 3 4];

%// rank of person in each classes
%//  class 1, class 2, class 3    
c = [   1       1       4       ;
        3       3       2       ;
        4       4       1       ;
        2       2       3       ];

%// weights of classes
w = [1 2 3];

%// score table
s = bsxfun(@mtimes,ndgrid(1:size(c,1),1:size(c,2)),w)

%// sum up points per person
ppp = accumarray(c(:),s(:))

%// overall ranking with class 3 as decisive row in case of tie
[~,o] = sortrows([ppp c(:,3)],[1 2])

%// overall rank of persons in order of person id
[~,r] = sort(o)

%// output
out = table(p(:),r, c, ppp, o,'VariableNames',{'person','rankOfPerson','classes', ...
                                             'OverallPointsOfPerson','overallRanking'})
```

---

```
out = 

    person    rankOfPerson      classes      OverallPointsOfPerson    overallRanking
    ______    ____________    ___________    _____________________    ______________

    1         2               1    1    4    12                       4             
    2         4               3    3    2    18                       1             
    3         3               4    4    1    18                       3             
    4         1               2    2    3    12                       2
```

Comment: Is there way I can adjust this code so that it deals with ties explicitly? Ideally I'd like to say that if scores between two students are tied we'll rank the one who did better on Math higher overall.

Comment: I understand. As things currently stand in your code, who would be ranked higher in the case of a tie?

Comment: @user1205901 the person with the higher rank in class 3